# Is Linux 3 kernel series compatible with CentOS 6?

Tags: centos6, linux-kernel, upgrade

For proper TPROXY support I was looking for a STABLE Linux kernel of at least version 3.2.30. Do they want us to upgrade to version 3 of the kernel? And is that compatible with CentOS 6?

Comment: The version number was bumped purely because the end numbers were getting a bit high. No other reason. Linus himself has said words to this affect.

Comment: @Sirex is right, but to make sure you have access to bugfixes and keep the management of the updates simple, you maybe should choose a distribution with a current kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, CentOS 6 supports running 3.2.30. Haven't tested it much, however.

Answer (score 0):

2.6.34.13 is the newest kernel, but it is not the highest version. Try the [web directory](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/) instead.

Comment: Google kernel 2.6.39, it exists.

Comment: @dongle26: Yes, it does. It is older than 2.6.34.13. The 2.6.34 line is being maintained separately.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. It is being maintained separately. The web directory contains the dates the kernel versions were released.

Comment: I really doubt that 2.6.34.13 contains features and patches found in 2.6.39.

Comment: No one claimed that it did. `/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/longterm/v2.6.34/linux-2.6.34.13.tar.gz: 20-Aug-2012`  `/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.39.4.tar.gz: 03-Aug-2011`

Answer (score 0):

If you need 2.6.39 you can use Oracle Linux, which is an RHEL clone that provides its own kernel (which just happens to be 2.6.39). I've used it in a couple of places to get driver support that wasn't present in 2.6.32.

Comment: Why is 2.6.39 not listed on the front page? I don't want to use an unstable kernel.

Comment: Because it hasn't been updated in more than six months. [This was answered in the kernel.org FAQ.](http://www.kernel.org/faq/#stablekernels)